# How I can combine two tasks in one

Tags: npm, sass, gulp, postcss

I have first task:

```
gulp.task( 'sass', function() {
    gulp.src('src/sass/**/*.+(sass|scss)')
        .pipe( sass({
                outputStyle:'expanded'
            }).on( 'error', notify.onError(
            {
                message: "<%= error.message %>",
                title  : "Sass mistake!"
            } ) )
        )
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css'));
});
```

And second:

```
gulp.task('optimize:css', ['sass'], function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        gulp.src('src/css/styles.css')
            .pipe(
                postcss([
                    autoprefix({
                        browsers:['>2%']
                   }),
                   stylelint(config),
                   stylefmt(config)
                ])
            )
            .pipe(gulp.dest('dev/assets/css'))
            .pipe(cssmin())
            .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('dev/assets/css'));
    },1000)
});
```

In second task I use setTimeout because if I run `optimize:css` without it - tasks will work async and actions in 'optimize:css' will not get me correct results

Is there a way to use one task instead two, without timeouts, in which I will get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You can find example of tasks dependencies definition into [Gulp documentation](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support).

In your case it would look like this:

```
// Notice "cb" argument here
gulp.task('sass', function (cb) {
    gulp.src('src/sass/**/*.+(sass|scss)')
        .pipe(sass({
                outputStyle: 'expanded'
            }).on('error', notify.onError(
            {
                message: "<%= error.message %>",
                title: "Sass mistake!"
            }))
        )
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css'))
        // And a fact that it is called at the end of the task
        .on('end', cb);
});

gulp.task('optimize:css', ['sass'], function () {
    gulp.src('src/css/styles.css')
        .pipe(
            postcss([
                autoprefix({
                    browsers: ['>2%']
                }),
                stylelint(config),
                stylefmt(config)
            ])
        )
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dev/assets/css'))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dev/assets/css'));
});
```